# Moq Repository returns 0 items

Tags: c#, get, repository, moq

I am trying to use Moq to simulate adding elements to a repository and then check the amount of elements that have been inserted, but it alway give me 0 elements, something is wrong in my code, can you please help me?

```
var candidate = new Candidate { Id = Guid.NewGuid()};            
var repo = new Mock<ICandidateRepository<Candidate>>();
repo.Setup(x => x.Insert(candidate));
repo.Setup(x => x.Submit());

candidateBL.setRepository(repo.Object);
MinifiedCount<MinifiedCandidate> result = candidateBL.Get(username, skip, take, id);
```

Inside candidateBL I checked the repository variable and has 0 elements.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `candidateBL`? Can you share code of `candidateBL.Get` method?

Comment: it's too long and doesnt really help to fix the problem, I commented the line where I set the repository and it gives me 5 elements, but I want to use a mock repository... thank you very much @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: I hope you're not expecting the `Insert` and `Submit` calls to put `candidate` into some repository somewhere...

Comment: How are you creating `candidateBL`?

Comment: Does candidateBL has to be created as Mock also? candidateBL is being created like this: candidateBL = new CandidateBL(); on TestSetup

Comment: Sorry @PatrickQuirk I am new to Moq, and it's being hard to manage the new concepts, thank you anyway

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing more of your code, I'm fairly confident you've fallen into the trap of thinking a mock of an interface somehow has logic in it related to your implementation of that interface.

In other words, it looks like you think that this code will actually insert `candidate` into your repository:

```
repo.Setup(x => x.Insert(candidate));
repo.Setup(x => x.Submit());
```

If that is your understanding, *that's not the case at all*.  The code above tells your mock to *expect* a call to `Insert` with the specified `Candidate` instance, and also to expect a call to `Submit`.  The methods of a mocked object have *no implementation*; they do exactly what you told them to do from the `Setup` methods.

Instead of treating the mock like an actual implementation, you need to tell it how to *respond* when used by your code under test.  For example, let's say that your `candidateBL.Get` method is something simple like this:

```
public Candidate Get(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        return _repository.Find(id);
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now imagine you're testing this method.  In the simple case, there are two test cases here: one where a single `Candidate` is found in the repository and returned, and another where the repository throws if the `id` doesn't exist.  You need to set up the mock to reflect these cases in each test.

The first test would set up the repository mock as follows:

```
var repo = new Mock<ICandidateRepository<Candidate>>();
repo.Setup(x => x.Find(candidate.Id)).Returns(candidate));
```

Note that no where did I insert the candidate; I instead told the mock to return it to me when I call `Find` with a specific identifier.

And for completeness, the second test would set it up to throw:

```
var repo = new Mock<ICandidateRepository<Candidate>>();
repo.Setup(x => x.Find(candidate.Id)).Throws(new KeyNotFoundException()));
```

Comment: Hi @PatrickQuirk my Get method is huge, it does a select on start and then filter the elements using Where expressions (linq). Can't I test my Get method itself?

Comment: Hey @PatrickQuirk I notice that doing this tests assume that candidate.Id already exists on the repository right? I want to do a clean repository and insert the elements there, then testing Get method with all optional arguments so I receive all elements inside the repository